Unexpected measurements results with prototype transformer-type inductive conductivity sensor (TICS)
I have made a prototype transformer-type inductive conductivity sensor (TICS) and I am getting some unexpected results at higher conductivity levels, so I am looking for some ideas for further testing to determine the cause.
General Principle
A sinusoidal drive signal is applied to a toroidal inductor (placed in a liquid) which induces an ionic current in the liquid proportional to the conductivity of the liquid. This ionic current in turn induces a current in the receiving coil which can be measured.

Representation of the internal build-up of the sensor:

Actual image of a commercial sensor (Knick SE655) with the same measurement principle:

Some images of my sensor:


Test Setup

Plastic beaker with 500 ml of reverse osmosis water on a magnetic stirring base and a small stirring stick in the beaker.
PT100 and reference conductivity sensor placed in the beaker on the side.
Prototype PCB with two toroidal inductors with a hole in the middle for the ionic current to flow, together with an NTC, all encased in clear epoxy. Toroids are placed in the middle of the beaker.
Table salt is added in small steps every 7-9 minutes to increase conductivity.

Prototype Design
Drive signal:

PWM 0-3.3V at 10 kHz with 50% duty cycle from MCU -> bias to 0V -> Buffer -> low pass filter with 10 dB gain -> 100 ohm current limiting resistor -> toroidal inductor (4 or 8.5 mH)
Toroidal inductor is either a NiZn core (4 mH, was found to be too temperature dependent during testing) or a nanocrystalline core (8.5 mH, vitroperm 500F, 15 windings)



Sense signal:

High pass / DC block -> Transimpedance amplifier with 1k Rf -> buffer -> band-pass @ 10 kHz with 20 dB gain -> precision rectifier -> averaging circuit -> 18-bit ADC with passive 1st order lowpass at the input.
Sensing inductor construction is identical to the driving inductor.




My results
For the first additions the ratio between the driving signal and the sense signal increases linearly with conductivity, however starting at about 3.5 mS/cm the response from the sensor seems to decrease over time and it seems to decrease faster with higher conductivity (see second picture).


Additional information

I used a different op-amp then shown in LTSpice, I used an OPA4197.
Conductivity is very temperature dependent, but the water temperature remains fairly constant just above 25°C so I do not think this is a factor.
I generate my -5V rail with a charge pump, so it is a bit noisy.
I turned off the magnetic stirring occasionally and I did not see a noticeable difference in the sensor output voltage.
Some waveform captures (sensing side) on the oscilloscope:

Some waveform captures (driving side) on the oscilloscope:

Before adding the high-pass filter between the sensing coil and transimpedance amplifier I did see a large offset of the sensing signal at these higher conductivity levels, however the offset was removed either way by the band-pass filter after the buffer.

I did a test where is simulated the water with salt by putting a wire through the hole in the toroids and connecting a resistor. The sensor output increases linearly with increasing conductance and does not drop over time at higher conductivity levels.



The great beauty about a toroidally wound inductor is that it doesn't produce an external magnetic field so, can you explain what your coils actually look like.

@Andyaka I have edited my post to add some pictures, both of my own prototype and a commercially available sensor.

Have you considered that at higher salt concentrations you AC drive signal may be reducing because of the loading effect of the extra-salty water?

You have some fairly high Q Sallen-Key filters in there- are you sure that nothing is saturating?

@Andyaka Good question, I have just looked at my logs again from that test and the drive signal seems to be constant throughout the entire test. I measure the driving signal in the same way as the sense signal (rectifying and averaging it, only without the gain).

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany I am not sure I understand your question correctly, could you clarify a bit? Do you mean the driving signal clipping against the supply rails? I will add an oscilloscope capture of the PWM signal and resulting drive signal in my post.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany The op-amps are rail to rail with an output voltage swing of a few 10 to a few 100 millivolts from the rail depending on the load. Peak to peak voltage of the driving signal is 7.3 volts and the supply rails are +5V and -5V, so I assume I have sufficient headroom.

@Burglups Coincidentally I just did such a test after writing this post, except I used a few discrete resistors instead of a potentiometer. I will add a graph to the post but basically the output voltage increases linearly with conductance and it also does not drop over time with a high conductance.
Regarding the coreless coils, I never considered those. I did some reading of articles and papers on the subject before making a prototype and I did not encounter coreless coils, I just used what everybody else used.

Don't know if this is important, but the relatively low value input capacitor causes the amplifier to deviate quite a bit from being a transimpedance amplifier- Z of 1uF at 10kHz is 16Ω, which is significant compared to 1kΩ. I don't see any point to R16, but it won't hurt anything.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany I could be wrong but I think C24 (1uF) on the input of the transimpedance amplifier does not significantly affect the result because the AC current which passes through C24 also passes through the feedback resistor R1 (1k), so I still measure the current being generated by the sensor. The feedback capacitor C3 (100p) could however introduce an error but it is limited to less than 1% if i calculated correctly.

@emdura You're indeed measuring the current that flows through the sensor but the sensor is not operating into exactly a virtual short so the current may be affected. I have not studied the paper in detail, but DOI:10.1016/j.sna.2019.111761 indicates that having a virtual short improves the characteristics.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany I also came across that paper, but I just assumed that they did not use a dual rail design because I see a TL431 precision voltage reference which they probably used for this 'virtual short'. I do have both a positive and negative supply so I don't really see a need for this virtual short. On another note, I did found the problem in the meantime.

After some more testing I found that the problem is indeed in my electronic design. I was driving my toroidal inductor into saturation. With my current design (6 Vpp drive voltage) and the NiZn core the current into my inductor looks like this:

Note how to sinewave becomes slightly distorted and harmonics are showing in the FFT, indicating saturation. I increased the drive voltage even more to 15 Vpp to make it more clear:

For comparison, the nanocrystalline core has better properties:

So in short, I need to decrease my drive voltage and/or use a better core to prevent saturation. My results now appear to be linear up to 20 mS/cm and no longer decrease over time. I am only curious why there was no issue with a wire and carbon resistor.
